# Python error: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

I need your help with my code. I have converted from `time.struct_time` to `datetime` object. Now I would like to convert it back to `time.struct_time` object after I have added to the next day date.

When I try this:

```
half_hour_date = '23/02/2018 23:00PM'
epg_time_1 = time.strptime(half_hour_date, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')

#convert from time_struct_time object to datetime
date_format = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(epg_time_1))
half_hour = date_format + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day)

#convert from datetime to time_struct_time object
epg_time_1 = time.strptime(half_hour, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
```

It give me an error: **TypeError: expected string or buffer**

The error are jumping on this line:

```
epg_time_1 = time.strptime(half_hour, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
```

Here is the datetime object for `half_hour`:

```
2018-02-23 23:00:00
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=23, tm_hour=23, tm_min=00, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=53, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Can you please help me how I can correct the error to allow me to convert it to `time.struct_time` object?

Comment: Maybe put in a string instead of a datetime?

Comment: Can you please show me an example how I could do this?

Comment: Why not just use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to create the `datetime` object directly from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
... import time
... 
... fmt = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%p'
... 
... half_hour_date = '23/02/2018 23:00PM'
... 
... date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(half_hour_date, fmt)
... half_hour = date_format + datetime.timedelta(days=2)  # self.program_day)
... 
... # convert from datetime to time_struct_time object
... epg_time_1 = time.struct_time(half_hour.timetuple())
>>> epg_time_1
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=23, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=56, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I can see it have now resolved the problem

Comment: @KnightRider Glad to help!

Answer (score -1):

There is no 23:00PM. Change it to 11:00PM.

#### [Update]

As you mentioned, the error came out from the second line. When I run the first two lines with Python 3.6, the result was

> ValueError: time data '23/02/2018 23:00PM' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p'

It means that there is a problem in "23:00PM" so I suggested to change it to "11:00PM". Or you can use "%H" instead of "%I" (as Patrick Haugh suggested in the comment).

P.S. I could not give full answer because of mobile device. Sorry for that.

Comment: Huh? cant you post an answer of what I am asking for?

Comment: The problem here comes from the incorrect hour directive `%I`.  `%I` is for 12 hour clocks, `%H` is for 24 hour clocks as outlined [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime).